# Linux Shell Script: Writing file and string together to another file

Tags: linux, string, bash, file, echo

This is my code is bash script:

```
for string in $LIST
do
echo "$string" >> file
grep -v "#" file1 >> file
done
```

"file1" contains only one value, and that value changes iteratively.

The result I get in "file" is:

```
a
1
b
2
c
3
```

However, I want this:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do You mean by this `"file1" contains only one value, and that value changes iteratively.`. Is it a named pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for string in $LIST
do
  echo "$string" $(grep -v "#" file1)
done > file
```